# How can I make a video fullscreen through javascript when a page loads?

Tags: javascript, plugins

I'm trying to make a plugin for a streaming service I use. When the next episode page loads through autoplay, it is not in full screen. I want to make it so that this automatically goes to full screen mode.

This website uses an iframe tag, with a video tag embedded inside of it. I have tried a simple:

```
var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]
vid.play();
vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
```

in the console, but I get the following error back:

```
Promise { "rejected" }
<state>: "rejected"
<reason>: TypeError: "Fullscreen request denied"
```

How can I go about this? Is it impossible? I have also tried to just simulate the "f" keypress, but it just returns true and does not actually seem to input into the screen.

Comment: Did you set the iframe up properly? i.e. `<iframe allowfullscreen="true"...`

Comment: @Jacob Here is how Crunchy Roll sets up their iframe

<iframe src="https://static.crunchyroll.com/vilos-v2/web/vilos/player.html" id="vilos-player" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media *" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: Are you using a Firefox plugin?

Comment: @Jacob right now I'm trying to make a Firefox plugin, yes, but I was just pasting that code in the console first to see if I can get it to work! My browser is firefox

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't test this code on the actual website you're working with, but it worked on youtube, so I think it'll work for your site as well.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

openFullScreen();
/* https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp */
```

This should work when pasted directly into the console.

#### Update

I tested the code on the link you referenced. A few things.

1. [crunchyroll.com](https://www.crunchyroll.com/) does not use a regular video player. So this line of code: `var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];` isn't finding the element you thought.
2. [crunchyroll.com](https://www.crunchyroll.com/)'s video player is using some reactive language. I tried to modify the class on the object and it just broke it. This means you can't modify it directly.

#### Solution

You have to sort through the console objects until you find the reactive js element that you need to control the full screen as intended. `VILOS_PLAYERJS.elem.requestFullscreen();` <-- Try that.

Also, in Chrome, if you play around with the `VILOS_PLAYERJS` object and its child `elem` you'll be able to do a whole lot more.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately not. I know I'm not being too helpful, I am not sure why the request is denied on Crunchy Roll and googling hasn't been useful. I don't know how to describe the issue any better :/ 

If you want to help you can try on a video on crunchyroll.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your code snippet, Jacob.

So, for me working this one:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("playlists-iframe")[0];

function openFullScreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

openFullScreen();
```

We could just use ClassName to get access for video in some players.